# Creating a skin engine in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, themes

Does anyone have any experience creating a skin engine for asp.net MVC? I know the suggested approach is to use flexible markup with CSS, but I would like the ability for a new view to be dropped in, and the application use that one instead of the default one.

Basically, I want to know how to tell the framework (at run time) to look into a specific folder for the views/content, and if the item isn't there to check the default locations.

I started to look into how the Oxite blog engine does it, but it seems like that might be a bit much for what I need (I am still looking through it, so I could be wrong.) Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the ViewEngine a little bit.

See this post http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2009/02/building-multi-tenant-applications-with_22.html

It can be done for partials and masterpage also.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me weed through the Oxite src, and understand what is going on.